# SQL Server Filling in Missing Record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've tried searching Google and reviewing StackOverflow and have found similar issues but none that seem to have helped with my specific issue.

There are two tables involved -

**#func** that lists the business functions responsible for reviewing an item.

**#review** which captures review status (In Review = 1, Complete = 2) of an item by each function.

Below is simplified schema and data.

```
CREATE TABLE #func
(
    funcId int,
    funcName varchar(25)
)

INSERT INTO #func VALUES (1, 'Marketing');
INSERT INTO #func VALUES (2, 'Safety');
INSERT INTO #func VALUES (3, 'Provisioning');
INSERT INTO #func VALUES (4, 'Boss');

CREATE TABLE #review
(
    itemId int,
    funcId varchar(25),
    reviewStatus int
)

INSERT INTO #review VALUES (1, 1, 2);
INSERT INTO #review VALUES (1, 2, 2);
INSERT INTO #review VALUES (1, 3, 2);

INSERT INTO #review VALUES (2, 1, 2);
INSERT INTO #review VALUES (2, 2, 2);
INSERT INTO #review VALUES (2, 3, 2);
INSERT INTO #review VALUES (2, 4, 2);
```

Joining the two tables produces "incomplete" results "omitting" a row for the Boss business function for itemId = 1.

```
SELECT r.*, f.*
FROM #func f
LEFT JOIN #review r ON f.funcId = r.funcId
ORDER BY r.itemId, r.funcId
```

| itemId | funcId | reviewStatus | funcId | funcName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | Marketing |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | Safety |
| 1 | 3 | 2 | 3 | Provisioning |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | Marketing |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | Safety |
| 2 | 3 | 2 | 3 | Provisioning |
| 2 | 4 | 2 | 4 | Boss |

I understand why this is happening but how do I get it to return results like below?

| itemId | funcId | reviewStatus | funcId | funcName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | Marketing |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | Safety |
| 1 | 3 | 2 | 3 | Provisioning |
| **1** | **4** | **0** | **4** | **Boss** |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | Marketing |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | Safety |
| 2 | 3 | 2 | 3 | Provisioning |
| 2 | 4 | 2 | 4 | Boss |

Comment: Ahhh, sample data with DDL and DML.  Most refreshing.

Comment: Your design is flawed: You have a missing relation (table) here called `item` which would have a list of possible `itemId`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cases like this you need to build a dataset of all possible combinations (`CROSS JOIN`) before left joining on your actual results. e.g.

```
SELECT i.itemId, f.funcName, COALESCE(r.reviewStatus,0) reviewStatus, f.funcName
FROM #func f
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT itemId
  FROM #review
  GROUP BY itemId
) i
LEFT JOIN #review r ON f.funcId = r.funcId and r.itemId = i.itemId
ORDER BY i.itemId, f.funcId
```

Comment: To be pedantic, `SELECT i.itemId, f.funcId, ISNULL(r.reviewStatus, 0) reviewStatus, f.funcId, f.funcName`, although eliminating the doubled `funcId` would likely be in order.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks!